# How to place ActivityIndicator center to the View

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am new to react-native, Actually i made one login component page, Whenever user pressed on login i have to show activity indicator. But here my problem is View contains some components in column direction, How can i place it.

code:

```
 <ImageBackground style={styles.imageStyle} source={require('../images/splash_background_landscape.png')}>
       <View style={styles.loadingStyle}>
            <ActivityIndicator></ActivityIndicator>
          </View>

        <View style={styles.parentViewStyle}>

        </View>



      </ImageBackground>



parentViewStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 20,
  },

loadingStyle : {
   flex :1
    justifyContent : 'center',
    alignItems : 'center'
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new class, `hudView.js` and re-use this for all loading screen,

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";

export default class hudView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          top: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center",
          backgroundColor: "rgba(110,110,110,0.5)"
        }}
      >
        <View
          style={{
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            backgroundColor: "transparent", //"rgba(255,255,255,1)",
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "center",
            borderRadius: 5,
            overflow: "hidden"
          }}
        >
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="red" />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And use it in your class,

eg:

```
...
import HudView from "../../components/hudView";
...


render() {
 return(
  ...
  ...
  {this.state.isLoading ? <HudView ref={"hudView"} /> : null}
)
}
```